# Child Objects Filter In EF

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

How can I filter child objects with entity framework by some criteria?
For example: I have object Company with ChildObjects, CompanyChilds. CompanyChilds have property active. I want to get Company with exact ID and Child Objects with active equals true.

I tried with this:

```
dbContext.Company.Include("ChildCompany").Where(x => x.Id == Id 
&& x.ChildCompany.Any(y => y.Active == true));
```

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: What is the problem that you're seeing with the query you described?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to filter child records in the Code First API -- see this post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx
See "Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities"

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you basically want the active children from the parent company..

```
var comp = dbContext.Company.Single(comp=>comp.Id == id);
var children = comp.ChildCompany.Where(cc=>cc.Active == true);
```

However, you may be able to query the children directly..

```
var children = dbContext.Company
         .Where(comp=>comp.ParentId == id && comp.Active == true);
```

Comment: I think second expression is not good. I know i can query child object with some parent id, but can i query child object from parent?